# Web scraping Yahoo financial statements -Balance sheet

Tags: python, data-analysis

I was trying to scrape balance sheet from Yahoo Finance using Python but couldn't get the expanded information.

What should I add to my code to get the detailed financial data?

Code used:

```
for table_row in table_rows:

    parsed_row=[]
    el=table_row.xpath('./div')

    none_count=0

    for rs in el:
        try:
            (text,)=rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
            parsed_row.append(text)
        except ValueError:
            parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
            none_count +=1

    if (none_count < 4):
        parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
```

Comment: Could you say exactly which page you are trying to scrape (or better yet the actual HTML you want), and show what your `import`'s are?

Comment: I'm trying to import these data from the following link : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/financials?p=TSLA

Comment: It would help if we know what result you're getting now